# Loading pandas DataFrame from parquet - lists are deserialized as numpy's ndarrays

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col2" : [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
})
df.to_parquet("./df_as_pq.parquet")
df = pd.read_parquet("./df_as_pq.parquet")
[type(val) for val in df["col2"].tolist()]
```

Output:

```
[<class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>]
```

Is there any way in which I can read the parquet file and get the list values as pythonic lists (just like at creation)?
Preferably using `pandas` but willing to try alternatives.

The problem I'm facing is that I have no prior knowledge which columns hold lists, so I check types similarly to what I do in the code. Assuming I'm not interested in adding numpy currently as a dependency, is there any way to check if a variable is array-like without explicitly importing and specifying `np.ndarray`?

Comment: Why?  A `numpy` array is almost always better.  There is virtually nothing you can do with a list you can't also do with an array.

Comment: @TimRoberts I updated the question with more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change this behavior in the API, either when [loading the parquet file into an arrow table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html#pyarrow-parquet-read-table) or converting the [arrow table to pandas](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.to_pandas).

But you can write your own function that would look at the schema of the arrow table and convert every `list` field to a python list

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def load_as_list(file):
    table = pq.read_table(file)
    df = table.to_pandas()
    for field in table.schema:
        if pa.types.is_list(field.type):
            df[field.name] = df[field.name].apply(list)
    return df


load_as_list("./df_as_pq.parquet")
```

Comment: Isn't there a simple method to serialize dataframes without changing the type at all?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, read it with `engine='fastparquet'`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1" : ["a", "b", "c"],
    "col2" : [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11,12]]
})
df.to_parquet("./df_as_pq.parquet")
df = pd.read_parquet("./df_as_pq.parquet", engine='fastparquet')
[type(val) for val in df["col2"].tolist()]
```

It will output `[list, list, list]`